# Syntax errors when decompiling with JD-GUI

Tags: java

I am aware that when decompiling a jar file, it is normal for the resulting .java files to contain syntax errors, but I am unsure of why and worse off I am sometimes unsure of how to fix these syntax errors. Take `int[] arrayOfInt = new int['Â€'];`, for example. Eclipse complains that `'Â€'` does not belong. Surprise! I know this already, but why does this happen. How can I find out what this value should be?

Comment: You should try out these decompilers all powered by procyon *[1](http://secureteam.net/Java-Decompiler.aspx)*, *[2](https://github.com/deathmarine/Luyten)*, *[3](https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it happens is because JD-Gui isn't encoding unicode properly. You can see that the thing inside the quotes is two bytes, and appears to be interpreted as nonstandard upper 128 characters. I.e. JD-Gui is emitting unicode, but the charset isn't declared correctly so your editor interprets it as two raw bytes in an 8bit charset instead of a single unicode character.

One solution is to use a Decompiler that emits unicode escapes instead of raw unicode byte sequences. That way, any editor will be able to view it correctly. I'd recommend Procyon (it's a lot better than JD-Gui anyway).

Comment: "raw unicode byte sequences" -> "raw UTF8 byte sequences". Only *probably* though, because the sequence translates to `C2 80`, or `0x80` translated back to Unicode, which is not a regular Unicode character at all. (It might just mean the *value* `0x80` but in that case the original decompiler really screwed things up.)

Comment: I didn't notice that. In that case, it's probably screwed up escaping of null characters (which have to be escaped specially in classfiles, but obviously not in source code).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Does Procyon also make obfuscated code easier to handle? The code that I am dealing with has obviously been tampered with, as it has variable names such as `str1`, `str2`, `str3`, etc.

Comment: For highly obfuscated code, Krakatau is the best. But if you're code is obfuscated, you can pretty much give up on getting a compileable result.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. By using Procyon, I was able to decompile the jar file into it's `.java` code files. Unlike JD-GUI's generated `.java` files, the ones created by Procyon only contained a single syntax error in one of the classes which was easily corrected. It would also appear that the jar file was not obfuscated, but JD-GUI's poor job at decompiling mangled the code so much that it appeared as though it had been messed with.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Luyten. It is a java decompiler just like JD-Gui, but it lacks much of the bugs inside jd-gui logic.

It is a front-end to Procyon.

PS: Sorry, I know i should commenting on Antimony's answer, but i don't have the necessary points to do that.

Comment: I've found that Luyten often lags behind the most recent version of Procyon, so I have to rebuild manually.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a look at Bytecode Viewer - https://github.com/Konloch/bytecode-viewer

It allows you to select from 3 different Java decompilers. It can also display the Bytecode and Hexcode of the Class file you select. (And more, check it out)